# How does this script work in CentOS7?

Tags: centos

I found a command in a CentOS7 tutorial to get a small table of the number of the user that try connect via ssh:

|`try`|`ip`|`user`|

The

The code is the next:

```
zgrep -hi "Failed password for " /var/log/secure* | sed "s/invalid user //" | tr -s " " | awk '{print $11" "$9}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20

zgrep -hi "Failed password for " /var/log/secure* | 
sed "s/invalid user //" | 
tr -s " " | 
awk '{print $11" "$9}' | 
sort | 
uniq -c | 
sort -rn | 
head -20
```

I want to know how its work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command searches your /var/log/secure log for failed login attempts

```
zgrep -hi "Failed password for " /var/log/secure*
```

will produce a result like this:

```
Aug  1 21:22:53 jbclamp001 sshd[40401]: Failed password for jbutryn from ip.ip.ip.ip port 55843 ssh2
```

**the command:**

```
sed "s/invalid user //"
```

Will search for the phrase "invalid user " and replace it with ""

**the command:**

```
tr -s " "
```

Will trim any extra blank characters from the string.

**The command:**

```
awk '{print $11" "$9}'
```

will then grab only column's 11 and 9 and print them (this is the IP address and username)

**the command:**

```
sort
```

will then sort all your results alphanumerically?

**the command:**

```
uniq -c
```

will remove any duplicate values

**the command:**

```
sort -rn
```

sorts the list in reverse numerical order?

**the command:**

```
head -20
```

will only show the top 20 values from your results.